# Couldn't find <model> without an ID, with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, nested-form-for

I have what should be a super simple form which I'm trying to use to update multiple records at once. I'm on Rails 3. I've been through all of the railscasts, etc and am pulling my hair out at this point. I'm using Devise, and have a contacts controller. Users have_many :contacts, and accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts. The form looks like:

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => '/updateusercontacts' do |i| %>
<%= i.fields_for :contacts do |f| %>    
    <%= f.label :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :firstname %>

    <%= f.label :last_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :lastname %>

    <%= f.label :phone_number %>
    <%= f.text_field :phonenumber %>
    <%= f.label :user_id %>
    <%= f.text_field :id %>
    <p>


<% end %>
```

The form displays properly, but then on submit I get "Can't find Contact without an ID". The controller looks like:

```
def updatecontacts
    @contacts = Contact.find(params[:id])
    @contacts.each do |contact|
        contact.update_attributes(params[:id])
    end

render '/home'

end
```

The parameters seem correct, and the id's seem to be present and correct, but I can't get the save to work! I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the fields_for and when you invoke your find, use this [:user][:contacts]
your code should look like this.
View:

```
  <%= form_for @user, :url => '/updateusercontacts' do |i| %>
    <%= i.label :first_name %>
    <%= i.text_field :firstname %>

    <%= i.label :last_name %>
    <%= i.text_field :lastname %>

    <%= i.label :phone_number %>
    <%= i.text_field :phonenumber %>
    <%= i.label :user_id %>
    <%= i.text_field :id %>
    <p>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
def updatecontacts
    @contacts = Contact.find(params[:user][:contacts])
    @contacts.each do |contact|
        contact.update_attributes(params[:user][:contacts])
    end

render '/home'

end
```

Hope this works.